# How to call a function inside the const click function using React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new with react and redux framework and I need help on how to invoke or call another function from within.
As you can see my code below from *ToggleSwitch.jsx* file. I have a click function and I want to call a toaster function
which displays a toast alert but it's not being invoked so I check on the console and it has an error log something like
"***Reference Error: toaster is not defined***". What did I miss here? Please guide me on how to resolve this type of scenario.
Thanks.

**ToggleSwitch.jsx**

```
const ToggleSwitch = ({ className, input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...rest }) => (
    <div>
        <Switch input={{ defaultChecked: input.value }}
            className={className}
            onChange={e => input.onChange(e.target.checked)}
            onClick={this.onCheckboxReturningLaterClick()}
            label={label}
            {...rest} />
        <input name={input.name} value={input.value} type="hidden" />
    </div>

)

const onCheckboxReturningLaterClick = () => {

      toastr.error(dude.messages.UNABLE_TO_PROCEED) 

}
```

Comment: you didnt pass any props, oncheckboxReturningLaterClick has acess to no functions.

Comment: well as i can see, there is no toastr defined...

Answer (score 1):

The `onCheckboxReturningLaterClick` function is not in `this` of the `ToggleSwitch` component. The syntax you have used for the component:

```
const Component = (props) => <h1>props.title</h1>
```

Is a stateless type of component.

Try to remove the `this` keyword when you're invoking `onCheckboxReturningLaterClick` in the `onClick` handler.

Another problem could be that... `toastr` is really not defined anywhere in the scope :)